# Logic that depends on database value that's constantly updated

Tags: mysql

So basically I have a function that will add a player to a team if the max players aren't already on a team. Since it does this asynchronously, if a bunch of users send requests at the same time, they will get the count before any other users join the team, which would update the count. Normally it checks the count and won't add the users if the count is greater than a certain number.. but because theyre querying the count before they update the database.. the count stays the same.

Comment: You are looking for a trigger and appropriate transaction logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give me some bare minimum psuedo code of how the logic should look like.

Comment: @joe If you want to get detailed responses you should describe the relevant tables and how you add a player to a team currently.